# iOS Swift - Data is not fetched quickly enough to reach another UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, fetch

I have a source view controller and a destination view controller.
I would like to show data fetched from a url in the UI (destination) just after moving to this screen ("show" segue).

In order to do that, in the source VC I use "prepare for segue" method, where I call a function that returns an array with all the fetched data I want to show and pass it to the destination VC to be shown in a UITableView.
The problem is that many times the whole data is not fetched from the url, so I pass an empty array to the destination.

This is the code in the source VC:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if let destinationVc = segue.destination as?
        ShowCharacterInfoViewController{

            fetchCharacterArrayFromUrl(characterName: cellContent){ results in

                destinationVc.array.append(contentsOf:results)
                destinationVc.tabelView.reloadData()}
} }
```

I can't think of a proper solution.

Comment: I would recommend fetching the data from the destination view controller in its viewDidLoad method

Comment: Don't call your `fetchCharacterArrayFromUrl` inside of the `prepare(for segue:)` function..... either call it before calling your segue, or call it after - in your destination view controller as @BJHStudios recommends

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of you. Can you explain the logic behind not calling it in the prepare method? I'm new to iOS, I learn a lot from these explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of two things.

1. Load the data and only perform the segue after the function has returned the data.
2. Transition to the destination screen and have that controller load the data in viewWillAppear.

   ```
   // Add a place to save the results
   var saveResults: MyResultsType?


   @IBAction func someButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

       // Consider putting a "Loading..." dialog here

       fetchCharacterArrayFromUrl(characterName: cellContent){ results in
           self.saveResults = results
           DispatchQueue.main.async({
               // Hide the "Loading..." dialog
               performSegue(withIdentifier: "ID of your Segue", sender: sender) // 
           })
       }
   }


   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if let destinationVc = segue.destination as? ShowCharacterInfoViewController {
               // I'm not sure append() is really what you need here
               destinationVc.array.append(contentsOf: savedResults)
               destinationVc.tabelView.reloadData()
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the need of using  DispatchQueue.main.async? Isn't that the default thread (I'm new with iOS)?

Comment: Also - if not append, what else?

Comment: I had to drop destinationVc.tabelView.reloadData() command since it's nil at this point. Other than that, your solution works for me.

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async` causes code to execute on the main thread where all UI code should run. It is needed whenever you do anything to the UI. Since `performSegue` causes a screen transition, you need to do that on the main thread.

Comment: You are right, but for some reason that I don't understand, if you put a UI code inside DispatchQueue.global.async{//code} it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the UI stuff in main thread since you are executing backend call:-

```
DispatchQueue.main.async({
 destinationVc.tabelView.reloadData()
})
```